# How can i go to next page after login with facebook using android?

Tags: android, facebook

i am making a login page where users are having options like if they click button(f continue with facebook)they can login through facebook and after login they can go to next page.
here i have put code of login with pagebook and it ask me password for facebook also.The problem is that after login also its remains on the same page.And if i logged in once then next time it will not ask me password for facebook and remains on the same page.

here is my code for Login.java:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String eml;
    private String pswrd;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status = "";
    private Button fbbutton;
    Profile profile;
    Button login;

    // private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    TextView tac1;
    EditText email, pass;
    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/login.php";
    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Get_hash_key();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        fbbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbtn);

        fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call private method
                onFblogin();
            }
        });

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        tac1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cAcc);

        tac1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {


                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, RegistrationForm.class));


                                    }
                                }

        );

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbtn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                eml = email.getText().toString();
                pswrd = pass.getText().toString();


                // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    //your intent code here
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username/password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("email", eml);
                        params.put("password", pswrd);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }

        });
    }


    public void Get_hash_key() {
        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.zeba.broccoli", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }




    private void onFblogin() {
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        try {
                            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                                        // profile2 is the new profile
                                        profile = profile_new;
                                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                    }
                                };
                                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                            } else {
                                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                            }

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                            // Application code
                                            try {
                                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                                String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                                String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                            //use shared preferences here
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

                            //go to Home page
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        //Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i guess you want to add this line `startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));`  inside this condition too `if (response.trim().equals("success")) {`

Comment: but tht is fine i can add tht but i need to do intent on f button...i tried putting intent thr but its nt working

Comment: is there any logcat error??...onSuccess() method called?

Comment: no...thr is no logcat error..but still its not working properly

Comment: hi, can u solve this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457829/how-to-fetch-single-data-from-server-into-textview-in-android-volley/41458283?noredirect=1#comment70132395_41458283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are couple of problems in your code: your are initiating your normal login in fb_login method...

Also in `onsuccess`() method you need to request permisssion for retreiving user details...

try below code:

Declare variable

```
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
Profile profile;
```

in your onCreate() replace:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Get_hash_key();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    fbbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbtn);

    fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call private method
            onFblogin();
        }
    });

    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    tac1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cAcc);

    tac1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {


                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, RegistrationForm.class));


                                }
                            }

    );

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbtn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            eml = email.getText().toString();
            pswrd = pass.getText().toString();


            // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //your intent code here
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username/password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", eml);
                    params.put("password", pswrd);

                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }

    });
}
```

Also in your fb_login method replace:

```
// Private method to handle Facebook login and callback
private void onFblogin() {
    callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // Set permissions
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                 @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        try {
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                        // profile2 is the new profile
                        profile = profile_new;
                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                    }
                };
                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
            } else {
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            }

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                            // Application code
                            try {
                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //use shared preferences here
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            //go to Home page
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home_page.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
         // Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
         //Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok let me try this one...but what abt shared preference ..is it neccessary?

Comment: depends on your app..if user close the app ,next time they have to login again without sharedpreference...

Comment: i m gettin error on profile it says cannot resolve profile

Comment: nothing is happening if i click f btn only pdialog box is showing

Comment: did u add facebook button and app id in mainfest??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132094/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-z-al).

Answer (score 0):

On Success save all required details in your **shared preference** and after that start your **main activity**. On restart application check your shared preference value in splash screen(first screen which opens when someone start application) if details are already present then directly go to **main activity** instead **login screen**.

Comment: sorry not getting...i have main page if i click imageview it will go to login activity..can u tell me through coding

Comment: you have main page where you  take user to login activity and then if fb login successful you take him to other activity. Next time you want if user opens your app he should directly goes to other activity?

Comment: yes it can also fine..but where m i going wrong with my code??

Comment: if person login with email and password then also he shud be able to go to next activity and if pressing facebook button(continue with facebook)then also

Comment: That's what I said above on fb or normal login success start your new activity as well as save your data(username,email) in `shared preferences`. So next time when you open your app you first check your 'shared preferences'  if data is data is available there in that case you can directly open your other activity. If you dont know about `shared preference` then go through this  link:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: i tried putting intent thr but thts not going to next activity

Comment: Are you able to login successfully? check logs you are getting user data or not.

Comment: yes if i type correct email and password then it shows login successful...but cant see any data thr? one more thing after putting facebook coding its not working

Comment: for now leave fb login try with normal email and password login which I provided in above link. Start with small problem.

Answer (score 0):

hi all i got the answer , first of all i did mistake by putting  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); AFTER 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
IT SHOULD BE BEFORE THAT ..THTS Y MY ACTIVITY WAS NOT GOING TO HOME PAGE