# how to fetch single data from server into textview in android volley?

Tags: android, mysqli, android-volley

i am new to android ,i am working on login and password activity where if you forgot the password then after typing your correct email the server will send the password into textview which should be set as settext.i made the php file but i am unable to made coding in android ..i want the data through volley .
here is my php file:

```
<?php 

include ('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE email='".$email."'";



$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'password'=>$row['password'],

    ));
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

here is my ForgotPassword Activity:

```
     public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String fremail;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    protected EditText femail;
    protected Button mSubmitButton;
    TextView pas;

    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/fpassword.php";




     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



          pas=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pas) ;
          femail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.feml);

          Button submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbtn);
          submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                fremail = femail.getText().toString();



                // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                try {
                                    JSONObject object     = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONArray jsonArray   = object.getJSONArray("result");
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

// fetch password from JSON
                                    String password         = jsonObject.getString("password");
// use password in textviewfemail.setText(password, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                                    pas.setText(password, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);



                                }
                                catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }


                            }

                        },

                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("email", fremail);


                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }

        });
    }








    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

here is my xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zeba.broccoli.Login">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logobr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">





            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">






                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/feml"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:hint="email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


          </LinearLayout>



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sbtn"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:elevation="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fpss"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Your Password is:" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pas"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"


                    />
```

I am not getting any error in logcat but when i run it on device it shows

```
jsonException....Index 0 out of 0 range[0...0]
```

Comment: **if you forgot the password then after typing your correct password**, what u doing pal.

Comment: mistake..after typing correct email

Comment: the user after clicking forgot password link will go to forgotpassword activity..there if he enters correct email then he should get password on settext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PHP` code is sending password in `JSON` format, first decode the `JSON` in your code and fetch the password:

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
pDialog.dismiss();

try {
JSONObject object     = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray   = object.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

// fetch password from JSON
// UPDATED HERE
String password         = jsonObject.getString("password");

femail.setText(password, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

} 
catch (JSONException e) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}  

},
```

PHP

```
<?php 

include ('config.php');

// updated here, value is mapped 
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE email='".$email."'";



$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//checking if email is valid or not
if(mysqli_fetch_array($r) == NULL){
echo "Invalid email";
}
else{
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'password'=>$row['password'],

    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: i m getting error on this  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: but how can they check if given email is valid or not if it valid then only it will show correct password that code is not thr...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132260/discussion-between-z-al-and-w4r10ck).

Comment: hi, i got the answer

Comment: it was my mistake..when i manually type email id in php code then only it works

Comment: Yep, I guessed it right. You are not mapping the email value from android to php, means your email string is not mapped with php script. Check my updated code for php.

Comment: no it says  value invalid of type java .lang.String.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i think its not email from app ...i think its android coding problm rathr thn php...

Comment: after correction in php where con is actually conn ....now i am getting jsonException....Index 0 out of 0 range[0...0]

Comment: paste the php output in form of JSON.

Comment: plz chk json output i posted

Comment: enjoy :) ur answer i ticked

Comment: hi this is z.al..this is also my account

Comment: here i can have chat ...coz here i have more badges so its o

Comment: i need to ask that can we tried another way to code..as i have tried that but thts giving me same error must b something.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132260/discussion-between-z-al-and-w4r10ck chat in room here

Answer (score 0):

use JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest

```
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObjectresponse) {
                          // you code here
 }
}
, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // add your header here
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
```

Comment: yes problm solved...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463967/not-getting-value-from-server-into-my-textview-using-android/41477360#41477360